# Convert multiple .jpg image files to a single docx file

Tags: image, jpeg, ocr, docx, doc

I have around 1000+ .JPG files ( which are images of printed text ), I want to take all of them and convert those images into a single .docx file with editable text.
I tried google drive option but it won't allow me to change more than one .jpg to google doc in one go.The other conversion options online won't take more that 10 or at most 20 files in one go with a limit of 150 mb maximum . The total file size I have is 2.4 gb . How do I achieve this? .

For example: Refer this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEcStLAS1hE  ( does it for a single JPG to google doc conversion (editable text) , but I want to do it for 1200 such images )

Comment: Do you mean you want 1,000 pages, with one image per page?

Comment: I have JPG images of a notebook (pictures of text book pages) , I want to convert those text images to actual editable text in word doc/docx/text  and I want to do this for 1200 such images to make a single doc/docx/text file with editable text  .

Comment: So you want OCR?

Comment: @MarkSetchell , I have already tried all online OCR's as I mentioned in the post they all have limit to maximum of 15 to 20 files in single conversion and have a maximum size limit of 150 mb or less , while I am looking at 1200 images of total size 2.4 GB.